# difference between claims provider trust and relying party trust

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs

what is the difference between **claims provider trust** and **relying party trust**. Is it right that when our application works as **service provider** then we have to configure **claims provider** at **ADFS** and when our application works as **Identity Provider** then we have to configure **relying party** at **ADFS**.

Comment: RP is for an application. CP is for another Identity provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Relying Party trust provides the configuration that is used to create claims. Once the claim is created, it can be presented to another Active Directory Federation Service or claim aware application. Claim provider trust determines what happens to the claims when it arrives.

Relying party is your resource (application) and it can be configured in the ADFS (usually it will be on the on-premises where the user authentication happens)

On the application end you need to create a claims provider trust in the ADFS.

Comment: so if my resource (application) acts as Service Provider then I have to configure both Relying Party Trusts and Claim Provider Trusts in ADFS?

Comment: The Relying Party trust provides the configuration that is used to create claims. Once the claim is created, it can be presented to another Active Directory Federation Service or claim aware application. Claim provider trust determines what happens to the claims when it arrives.
Relying party is your resource (application) and it can be configured in the ADFS (usually it will be on the on-premises where the user authentication happens)
On the application end you need to create a claims provider trust in the ADFS.

Comment: Thanks, you explained it very very well